# ProtocolError: No protocol version header

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, thrift, happybase

I have hortonworks cluster with versions as below:

- hbase = 1.1.2
- happybase=1.1.0
- hortonworks hadoop cluster = HDP-2.6.2.0

When I try to run simple example:

```
import happybase
server = "server-address"
connection = happybase.Connection(server)
print connection.tables()
```

I got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/psobolewski/hbase_urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    print connection.tables()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 242, in tables
    names = self.client.getTableNames()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 439, in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6470)
cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the right port as well as the right address? It seems unlikely your server's address really is "server-address" - what is the address really?

Comment: Also, are you using the correct `transport` and `protocol` as per http://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#connection ?

Comment: @TomDalton i connect to the right address and port. Port is open for my host also.

Comment: Did you solve the  issue? I have the same problem trying to put new data

Answer (score -2):

Try to change port=2181 and check hbase-site.xml

Comment: Hi Samat. I think it would help if you would said in hbase-site.xml where did you find the port 2181 because normally the port  2181 doesn't mean that  all people will use the same port.